# Incorrect Razor ternary syntax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Im copied this ternary from another SO post:

```
  <td><input type="button" value="Delete" class="DeleteButton" id="@("D" + param.QueueId)" @{ if(param.StatusId != 1) { @:disabled="disabled" } } /></td>
```

But it is causing compilation errors.

End of file or an unexpected character was reached before the input tag could be parsed.

Comment: I see no 'ternary' here

Comment: Oh yeah you're right. because of course a ternary is the eqivalent of an if else. My bad. Ill vote your comment up for its sheer helpfullness, my only regret is I cant give bonus points for the single quotes and the added sting they have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@:` is causing the problem, since it doesn't know where the output ends and Razor starts, try to replace it with:

```
<text>disabled="disabled"</text>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to change:

```
@{ if(param.StatusId != 1) { @:disabled="disabled" } }
```

to:

```
@(param.StatusId != 1 ? "disabled='disabled'" : string.Empty)
```

Comment: Thankyou, but Ill accept haims answer purely because I dont want to use an else to output string.empty.